# How many triggers we can have on a single table in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, triggers, database-administration

I have a confusion on maximum numbers of different type of triggers we can have on a single table in oracle db.

Comment: There is no limit. You can have as many triggers for the same event on a table. But, if you are keen to develop such a system where you reach a practical limit of number of triggers on a single table, then no doubt it will be a brainfart utterly stupid system.

Comment: But some on internet saying we can have 12 no of same trigger.

Comment: That is plain wrong. oracle doesn't stop you to create multiple triggers for the same event. Just try it and see. Also, from 11g on wards, compound triggers are supported. So, 12 is plain wrong. You can have as many.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, As you suggested let me try in my local db.

Comment: There is no limit. You can create as many as you want. But With Oracle 9.0 or below maximum number of triggers is 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you encounter any problems due to any limit?

You can have triggers of these timing points:

- BEFORE statement triggers
- BEFORE row triggers
- AFTER row triggers
- AFTER statement triggers

In case you have more than one trigger at a timing point the order of execution is undetermined, thus it should be very uncommon to have many triggers for the same timing point.

Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_trigger.htm#BABGFHID) says:

*You cannot control the order in which multiple row triggers fire.*

*If two or more triggers are defined with the same timing point, and the order in which they fire is important, then you can control the firing order using the [FOLLOWS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_trigger.htm#CJADJGIF) clause.*

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one trigger at same point of time.
You can achieve that using FOLLOWS keyword while creating trigger.

Comment: I agree with your. The Oracle 11g trigger syntax now includes the FOLLOWS clause to guarantee execution order for triggers defined with the same timing point.